# Calling Powershell script in nested folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file for setting up new computers in my company:

- activates the local Administrator account and sets the password
- activates Windows
- calls up a PowerShell script to rename the PC
- fires up a batch file that installs basic programs like Office.

However, I want to change it so a batch file that can process several different options (this will be done using the `set /p` command) will use the appropriate PowerShell scripts that will be moved to a folder in the same directory.

Also want to make note that these will be running off of a USB drive, so the drive letter isn't always the same (example: `%flashdrive%\tools\PS_Scripts`)

The batch file will be saved in the `Tools` folder, while the script repository will be the `PS_Scripts` folder.

How should I edit the command to the appropriate syntax to run the scripts from the nested folder?

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Comment: So you have a batch file that runs Powershell that runs Powershell.  A bit confused by that.

Comment: Allow me to clarify: I have a batch file that runs a powershell script.  That script does several commands, including invoking a separate batch file once the initial steps are completed, then the script closes.  The powershell script isn't running other powershell script.  Basically I want to know what the command should be to run the appropriate powershell scripts in the folder located in the same directory from that initial batch file

Comment: In your snippet, you're calling powershell from powershell.  It's unnecessary.  Just use the `-File` parameter on the first powershell call.

Comment: Okay I think this is worded incorrectly.  I just want to know what changes I need to make to the command in the batch file to call the necessary powershell script in the nested folder.  That's it.  Don't get hung up on what the script does, just need to know an answer for how to call the scripts from the batch file

Comment: You already have a clue in your code: `"%~dpn0.ps1"`.